# String or Binary data would be truncated on insert with select subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, truncate

Typically, that error means one of the fields is too small to contain the length of the data. So that's where I started. I padded X's before and after values to check for spaces, and I used LEN to check the length of the data, and I can't find anything wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP1 (BUSINESS_UNIT VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
NATIONAL_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ACCOUNT_BALANCE DECIMAL(12, 2) NOT NULL,
STRM VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FIRST_NAME_SRCH VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME_SRCH VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
COMMON_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL)


INSERT INTO TEMP1 (BUSINESS_UNIT, NATIONAL_ID, ACCOUNT_BALANCE, STRM, 
FIRST_NAME_SRCH, LAST_NAME_SRCH, COMMON_ID)
(SELECT ASF.BUSINESS_UNIT, NATL.NATIONAL_ID, ASF.ACCOUNT_BALANCE, '1162'
,NM.FIRST_NAME_SRCH,NM.LAST_NAME_SRCH,ASF.EMPLID
FROM PS_ACCOUNT_SF ASF (NOLOCK)
, PS_NAMES NM (NOLOCK)
, PS_PERS_NID NATL (NOLOCK)
WHERE ASF.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'ABCDEFG'
AND ASF.ACCOUNT_TERM = '1162'
AND ASF.ACCOUNT_BALANCE > 0
.......... more code, etc.
```

The Select returned 15 rows.
Sample row:

```
ABCD1   123456789   46.30   1162    JOHN    SMITH   12345678
```

Now, I was able to figure out that it's the EMPLID field because when I comment out the ASF.EMPLID field in the select and hard-code something like '12345678' it was successful. But I checked the lengths of the returned values, and they were all 8.

It's worth noting that the selected field ASF.EMPLID is VARCHAR(11), and the destination field is VARCHAR(8). 
My solution was to just change COMMON_ID VARCHAR(8) to VARCHAR(11) and it worked fine.
But my question still remains... does that matter if the length of the value is 8? Or is something else happening?

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-GDR)

Comment: You already found the "issue".  The source is 11 characters and the destination is 8 characters -- this warning is just letting you know that you may lose 3 characters.

Comment: it threw an error and stopped processing. 'SQLExecute error...The statement has been terminated'
but then, so what you're saying is - it does matter that the source and destination field lengths don't match even if the length of the value is ok

Comment: Yes this is a warning that will not work unless you fix it.  So do a cast and make it explicit if that is what you want or make your destination bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try using substing or left 
Set max len to 8 eg 
select left(field, 8) from table
If this works then you know you have truncation issues. ie some field is > 8